# Execute command doesn't work - Minecraft 1.16.3

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map and I want every time a player walks on top of an orange terracotta block, the player receives levitation for 1 second. The problem is when I run the command, the game just does nothing, there is no output even with `/gamerule commandBlockOutput true`.

```
execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~ ~ minecraft:orange_terracotta run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1 40 true
```

This is the command I am using; I've put it in a command block with repeat mode, unconditional and needs redstone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `~ ~-1 ~` or something like that. You are saying at the specific block that the player is at. If you do `execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:orange_terracotta run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1 40 true` it will do the block under the player.

Comment: I have checked this and this DOES actually work. If you have a world download now, I would LOVE to see your map :)